# In selenium, I am able to find the element by using xpath locator. Its also returning the element text .But it is not clicking on the webelement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please find the selenium code below where I am find the WebElement , Printing it Text and then clicking on it:

```
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Create']"));
System.out.println(element.getText());// its returning the text
element.click(); // but its not clicking
```

HTML code Below:

```
<div id="gtn-navbar" class="gtn-navbar inverse ">
<header class="nav cf">
<ul class="primary-nav">
<li class="tab">
<li class="tab icon home">
<li class="tab ">
<li class="tab ">
<li class="tab ">
<li class="tab icon-new-document icon iconAndLabel ">
<!-- MENU/TAB KEY: create -->
<a id="navmenu__create" title="Create" href="#" gtnexusnavinitialized="true">
<svg class="icon">
<use xlink:href="#icon-new-document"/>
</svg>
**<span class="label">Create</span>**
</a>
```

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work and the error stacktrace please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the ID navmenu__create to find element and click.